# jQuery ajax call is returning response data as String instead of Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, axios, xmlhttprequest

On the following `StackBlitz`:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-jbthdw?file=src%2FApp.js

I have a code which fetches a `JSON` data with a list of names.

There are two ways of returning data: `Axios` and `jQuery`.

With the `Axios` approach the code works properly.

Now, because some business decisions I need to replace `Axios` with `jQuery`.

**My problem is:** with `jQuery` the `response.data` is fetched as `string` when it should be as `object` as it happens with `Axios`.

Below you have the code, but feel free to play with the `StackBlitz` playground I provided above:

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import $ from 'jquery';
import './style.css';

export default () => {

  const jsonSource = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tlg-265/mockend/master/data.json';
  
  const handleClickAxios = () => {
    axios.get(jsonSource).then(response => {
      console.log({ responseType: (typeof response.data)});
      console.log(response.data);
    });
  };

  const handleClickJQuery = () => {
    sendApiRequest({ url: jsonSource, method: 'get' }).then(response => {
      console.log({ responseType: (typeof response.data)});
      console.log(response.data);
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Axios vs jQuery</h1>
      <p><b>Inconsitency:</b> returning response as Object vs String</p>
      <button onClick={handleClickAxios}>Axios</button>{' '}
      <button onClick={handleClickJQuery}>jQuery</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export const sendApiRequest = ({
  url,
  method,
  data,
  timeout,
}) => {
  method = method.toUpperCase();

  let additionalSettings = { data: data };
  if (method === 'POST') {
    additionalSettings = {
      contentType: 'application/json',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: JSON.stringify(data),
    };
  }

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    $.ajax({
      url,
      method: method,
      timeout,
      ...additionalSettings,
      success: (response) => {
        resolve({
          data: response
        });
      },
      error: ({ responseJSON }) => {
        reject(responseJSON);
      },
    });
  });
};
```

Here you have a screenshot of the issue:

[image]

Any idea on what do I need to update on the code in order to get: `response.data` as `object` with `jQuery`? I need to get that without any post processing of the response. Is there maybe any params I could use with `jQuery` so it behaves similarly to `Axios`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL you are requesting includes this response header:

> ```
> content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
> ```

Which is why jQuery isn't processing it as JSON automatically.

A quick search of [the documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) for the word "json" quickly brings up the `dataType` option which lets you override the content-type.

```js
const jsonSource = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tlg-265/mockend/master/data.json';

jQuery.ajax({
  url: jsonSource,
  dataType: 'json'
}).then(data => {
  console.log({
    responseType: (typeof data)
  });
  console.log(data);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: my issue is not with `axios` which is fine (`responseType: object`). My issue is with `jQuery` (`responseType`: `string`). Please check the screenshot on my question above. Because business decisions, I'm forced to replace: `axios` with `jQuery`. Then, I need `jQuery` to return the response as an `object` instead of a `string`.

Comment: Then you want `dataType`. Note that jQuery returns a promise. Don't use the creating new promises antipattern, https://runnable.com/blog/common-promise-anti-patterns-and-how-to-avoid-them

Comment: you are right, on my code for `GET` method I was not specifying: `dataType: 'json'` and that was the cause of the issue. Answer accepted. Thanks!